# How to display NSArray objects using dictionary in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is my viewcontroller.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

{

    NSArray *sectionTitleArray;
}

   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * tablevw;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tablevw.delegate = self;
    _tablevw.dataSource = self;



    sectionTitleArray = @[ @{@"text": @"About Step0ne"},
                           @{@"text": @"Profile"},
                           @{@"text": @"Matches"},
                           @{@"text": @"Messages"},
                           @{@"text": @"Photos"},
                           @{@"text": @"Settings"},
                           @{@"text": @"Privacy"},
                           @{@"text": @"Reporting issues"},
                           ];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {

    return sectionTitleArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text"];

        return cell;
}
```

I am new to Xcode am getting output as in every tableview cell first object i.e About Step0ne is displaying i need all objects should be displayed in UITableView cell.Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have "count" sections, each with one row, you need to change this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text"];
```

to:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"text"];
```

BTW - this can be written more easily as:

```
cell.textLabel.text = sectionTitleArray[indexPath.section][@"text"];
```

Or, if you really want one section with "count" rows, leave that line as-is and update your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` accordingly.

Comment: If i need 8 sections as per my requirement how should i modify the above code.

Comment: Oddly it seems you posted this comment after accepting the answer so I'm not sure why you are asking. The 1st half of my answer explains what to do when you want one row per section.

Comment: Now i have another requirement related to this only just small modification can you guide me.

Comment: instead of one array i have 8 arrays.How should i display in tableview

Comment: You should post a new question with the relevant details.

Answer (score -1):

replace bellow two methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
return sectionTitleArray.count;

}
```